# how i can use mysql_error() function if i use php with sql server(mssql) or oracle

Tags: php

how i can use mysql_error() function if i use php with sql server(mssql) or oracle ?

Comment: lol *_* oky tell me any function can make same job

Comment: You shouldn't be using the antiquated mysql or mssql extensions in any case. It's been twice supplanted. At this point, you should be using [PDO](http://php.net/PDO). For SQL Server, there's the [SqlSrv PDO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628175.aspx) driver. Also, be careful you don't display DB errors to anyone but an administrator, else you'll be [disclosing too much information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995351.aspx#securityerrormessages_topic2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use mysql_error with myssql or oracle databases.

they have their own

[mssql_get_last_message](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-get-last-message.php) for mssql.

[oci_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php) for oracle.

Comment: oky and what about mysql_real_escape_string is there any function do same jop with oracle and sql server? and i ask about, mysql_insert_id()

Comment: @user646645: The easy way to find the function is to go with PHP manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php you can find here all the functions of databases

Comment: i know but i cant find function like mysql_escap_real_string and mysql_insert_id for sql server and oracle