# i need function like mysql_real_escap_string() and mysql_insert_id() work with sql server and oracle

Tags: php, sql-server, oracle

i need function like mysql_real_escap_string() and mysql_insert_id() work with sql server and oracle i searched in mysql manual and didnt find what i need

Comment: How is this any different than [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603266/how-i-can-use-mysql-error-function-if-i-use-php-with-sql-servermssql-or-oracl)?  Shakti Singh was nice enough to point you at the *complete manual* listing the relevant functions...

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching for a function related to SQL Server or Oracle, you should not search in the MySQL manual -- but in the section related to the DB engine you're interested in...

- For MS SQL Server :

  - The [`mssql_*` functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php).
  - Or the [MS SQLSRV Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296152%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).
- For Oracle : [OCI8](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php)

Comment: i try but cant find what i need

Comment: @user, that is because those drivers use prepared statements and have no need for "real escape string."  Further, the way each does identity columns is very different than MySQL.  I heartily encourage you to read *the entire manual sections* for the functionality that you require.  Doing so will help you learn how to use the tools available to you effectively.  (This isn't just some dude on the 'net telling you to RTFM here -- these extensions and databases are *very different* than MySQL and you *must* know how to use them properly and effectively to get the job done!)